# AzureML: How to Keep leading zeros in dataset (.CSV)

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

My data: `0671001795`

Dataset in Microsoft AzureML: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfCtu.png

How to Keep leading zeros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping leading zeros when the data column is in integer format is not possible. Here's an alternative way of keeping the leading zeros. (The String data type is used instead of int)

1. Add an special character('/' etc) before the number
2. Pipe the contentthrough 'Preprocess Text' module.
3. Make sure only to tick "Remove Special Characters" option.
4. Output would be in a string with your desired format.

[image: Remove Special Characters option]

[image: Output as a string]